# Modify css so as to not change text color

Tags: css

I am using HTML and css from sharingbuttons.io for social media buttons on a web site.

The neural button is fine:
[image]

The hover button
[image]

changes the fill color as desired. But it also changes the text color. I want the text to remain white. How do I do that?

CSS

```
.resp-sharing-button__link,
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  display: inline-block
}

.resp-sharing-button__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5em
}

.resp-sharing-button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 25ms ease-out;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

.resp-sharing-button__icon svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  vertical-align: top
}

.resp-sharing-button--small svg {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}

/* Non solid icons get a stroke */
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: none
}

/* Solid icons get a fill */
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solid,
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solidcircle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: none
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover {
  background-color: #525250
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover {
  background-color: #525250
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover {
  background-color: #525250
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #3b5998;
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:active {
  background-color: #525250;
  border-color: #525250;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee;
  border-color: #55acee;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--twitter:active {
  background-color: #525250;
  border-color: #525250;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777777;
  border-color: #777777;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--email:active {
  background-color: #525250;
  border-color: #525250;
}
```

HTML

```
!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Facebook">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--facebook resp-sharing-button--medium"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.77 7.46H14.5v-1.9c0-.9.6-1.1 1-1.1h3V.5h-4.33C10.24.5 9.5 3.44 9.5 5.32v2.15h-3v4h3v12h5v-12h3.85l.42-4z"/></svg></div>Facebook</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add `color: #fff;`? Like this:

```
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #525250;
  border-color: #525250;
}
```

Comment: I see how your solution makes the text white. But what turns it blue?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is this the whole CSS code?

Comment: Yes. I added the relevant HTML to the question.

Comment: I think thise are the scripts from sharingbuttons.io. Maybe you have added some CSS in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

On this:

```
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover {
 background-color: #525250
 }
```

you can just say
color: #fff or white;
but if you are specifically targeting the facebook text, I guess just add a div around the

tags you have give it a class, and do

```
color: #fff;
```